# ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource does not seem to copy the pixels

Tags: directx-11

I am trying to copy the pixels from a source `ID3D11Texture2D` into a shared destination texture. My goal is to create a shared handle and export it to another application. For the copying process, I use `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource`, but it doesn't seem to work properly. When I opened the shared handle (using `ID3D11Device1::OpenSharedResource1` or `OpenSharedResourceByName`), the image is all black, but I got the correct dimension. Does anyone know how I can debug this? I believe both the source and destination textures were created with similar descriptions, and the only differences are the destination's `CPUAccessFlags` is 0, and its `MiscFlags` is `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE | D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX`.

Many thanks,
Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

OK a colleague of mine figured out a solution. The `CopyResource` line should be locked before and unlocked after calling, e.g.:

```
ComPtr<IDXGIKeyedMutex> mutexA;
hr = dxgiResource.As(&mutexA);

// GPU Copy the original 
mutexA->AcquireSync(0, ...);
dxContext->CopyResource(dxSharedTexture.Get(), dxTexture.Get());
mutexA->ReleaseSync(1);
```

and when retrieving the texture, do the same thing.

```
ComPtr<IDXGIKeyedMutex> mutexB;
hr = pTexture2D.As(&mutexB);
hr = mutexB->AcquireSync(1, ...);
// Retrieve the image
// ....
mutexB->ReleaseSync(0);
```

Note that `mutexA` and `mutexB` have opposite keys. You lock the first the first texture with key 0 and unlock it with 1. For the second texture, it is the other way around.

Further read: [[link]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis)